# После истечения срока акаунта разработчика Apple приложение удаляется из AppStore?

Tags: appstore

Было разработано и опубликовано небольшое бесплатное приложение для IOS. Больше разрабатывать ничего не планируется. Но по истечению аккаунта приложение приобрело статус "Ожидание договора" и AppStore говорит что приложение "недоступно в Вашем регионе". Это как-то связано, или приложение удалили по другой причине?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно Apple по позволяет распространять приложения с истекшим аккаунтом разработчика. Пока не продлишь - приложение будет недоступно в AppStore.

Answer (score 1):

Если срок Вашего членства истек, пользователи по прежнему смогут загружать, устанавливать и запускать приложения, подписанные с соответствующим ID разработчика. Однако, если срок членства истек, необходимо быть членом программы Apple Developer Program чтобы получить новый ID разработчика, чтобы выпускать обновления и новые приложения.

> недоступно в Вашем регионе

Ясновидящих тут нет. [Обратитесь в поддержку](https://developer.apple.com/support), напишите простое письмо на английском, ничего сложного.